# Public field from String - How can you get a public field vis its name(string)

Tags: java, class, field, public

So in a class (ImportantClass123) I have this:

```
public AnotherImportantClass aReallyImportantClass;
```

How do I return

```
AnotherImportantClass
```

via knowledge of what its named as a field:

```
aReallyImportantClass
```

Something like

```
ImportantClass123.getFieldWithName("aReallyImportantClass");
```

?

How would I write getFieldWithName? and what would be its return type? Class?

Comment: you'll need something like reflection api, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html

Comment: @shmosel OP is looking for the type of the field, not the value. Surprisingly I can't find a duplicate for that.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yup, I missed that.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get to that information. The method `Class.getField(String)` returns a `Field` object for the public field given by name. And the Field object has a method `getType()` that will give you the type of that field:

```
public class Snippet {
    public Integer x;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field x = Snippet.class.getField("x");
        Class<?> type = x.getType();
        System.out.println("Type of field x: " + type);
    }
}
```